# Run C program as admin first time

Tags: c, windows, winapi, administrator

I made a program that has to run as admin just to create one registry key. After my program created the registry key I create another key in the registry to run my program on startup, I don’t need admin rights for this. So I changed the project properties so that if the user wants to run my program he/she has to run it as admin. After the creation of my first key(where I need admin rights), I add my program to startup using the registry.

The problem is that we can’t run the program with admin rights on startup. I don’t even need admin rights after the first execution because the neccesary key is created.

My question: How can I make my program so that it only asks for admin rights on the first execution?

Comment: *"How can I make my program so that it only asks for admin rights on the first execution?"* - You're asking for an installer.

Comment: I don't know why you're being down voted, it seems like a reasonable question. I don't think there's an answer though.

Comment: @IInspectable that should be an answer, because I think it's the only thing that works.

Comment: @YK You don't need admin rights to write to the `Run` key in HKCU.  Are you trying to write to the `Run` key in HKLM instead?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Writing to run goes succesfully without admin rights. I need admin rights to write to SOFTWARE/Policies. From my understanding you can write everywhere under HKCU except for the Policies section.

Comment: @YK in that case, I agree with IInspectable, this is probably better handled with an installer, not your main app.

Comment: @RemyLebeau This was helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have in memory two processes of the same program, and maybe have them communicate with a pipe. The user starts the program normally without elevated privileges. Once the elevation is required you start the same program with `ShellExecuteEx` and verb "runas". This "runas" verb will cause UAC prompt.

If you need elevated privileges only once for the whole duration of the original process, then you can pass some parameters to the elevated process, and be done with it. But if you need elevated process to perform several actions, at different times, then you have to have a pipe open between two processes, to send data to the elevated process. This way you have UAC prompt only once, but do stuff that need elevation any time you need.

Comment: "*you have to have a pipe open between two processes, to send data to the elevated process*" - or, you can simply pass the data as command line parameters. The elevated app can check its parameters at startup, perform the requested action(s), and then exit.

Comment: @Remy that means the elevated process ends, and the next time you need something elevated done you have to create a new elevated process. With new UAC prompt.

Comment: In this situation, yes, because there is only 1 elevated task being used, so the pipe approach is overkill.  For multiple tasks, an alternative would be to wrap the tasks inside of a COM object that gets created when needed using the [Elevation Moniker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/the-com-elevation-moniker), then you don't need a separate process. But that would be overkill for a single task, too.

Comment: Why do I have to create 2 processes?

Comment: @YK once the process is created it's elevation status cannot be changed. The status is set by process loader at the start. So, if you need higher elevated process, there has to be a new process.

Comment: @Dialecticus When I use ShellExecuteA() in a blank program to start itself with "runas", it replicates itself unlimited times. This is my whole program: HINSTANCE r = ShellExecuteA(NULL, "runas", "ConsoleApplication1.exe", NULL, NULL, 0); When I put another exe in the third argument it works fine. Guess I have to first create a process and then inside that process I have to call ShellExecuteA()

Comment: After I wrote this comment I found why. It's because when it calls itself the new exe also calls itself and so on.